ключевое слово _Packed в Си
Наткнулся на сайт по изучению Си, в котором была таблица ключевых слов, среди которых есть "_Packed". В интернете нашёл лишь один сайт, который слишком сложно объясняет его значение.
Кто знает, что это и как его использовать? Буду рад услышать, тем более в книгах этого не видел, может для многих это будет что-то новое.

packed для структуры означает, что ее поля будут располагаться в памяти сплошняком, без естественного выравнивания

я новичок, совсем ничего не понял(

Тогда почитайте для начала книжку, например, K&R

её я в данный момент и читаю..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment
